# Convert an image button to a submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I've been given the following HTML and JavaScript by a front end designer.  Now I tried different ways to convert it to a button:
Below is the designers html

```
 <div id="detailsdiv" style="left:580px; width:100px;">
            <input type="image" name="submit" onMouseOver="lg.src='images/b_logB.png'" onMouseOut="lg.src='images/b_logA.png'" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
            <a href="home.html" onMouseOver="lg.src='images/b_logB.png'" onMouseOut="lg.src='images/b_logA.png'">
                <img src="images/b_logA.png" name="lg" class=style1></a>
        </div>
```

I tried this:

```
<input type="image" name="submit" onMouseOver="lg.src='images/b_logB.png'" onMouseOut="lg.src='images/b_logA.png'"
                   src="images/b_logB.png" border="0" alt="Submit" class="style1" />
```

But its not working, it just displays a the first button, it doesnt change on mouseOver

Comment: <input type="image" name="submit" onMouseOver="lg.src='images/b_logB.png'" onMouseOut="lg.src='images/b_logA.png'" 
                   src="images/b_logB.png" border="0" alt="Submit" value="" >

Comment: You should change name attribute to something else than submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try like this.......

```
<input type="image" name="submit" onMouseOver="this.src='images/b_logB.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/b_logA.png'" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('formid').submit();" />
```

in `onclick` method of image the form is manually submitted by javascript.

`this` refers to image.

Comment: You should explain what you've changed and why will it work. Currently, it's not really a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just open the Input tag and then have the img tag inside it?

```
<input type="submit"><img src="http://www.google.com/image.png"></input>
```